# Python imgkit make a screenshot on specific div block

Tags: python, html, image, screenshot, imgkit

I have troubles with creating screenshots using imgkit. I can easily make a screenshot full site, but I don't know how to screenshot only specific div block in html. I'm totally noob in html, I don't think it is good idea to learn it for one python script...

For example, make a screenshot only for this google block

[image: screenshot]